# Cannot access 'java.lang.Object' error with new Android Studio Electric Eel

Tags: android, android-studio, java-11, java-9

I just installed the new `Electric Eel` Android Studio stable version, but I am getting the following error messages below although the project builds without errors. The errors are happening in the `build.gradle.kts` file for the `buildSrc` module. What do I have to do to resolve the error messages?

```
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.`kotlin-dsl`

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

[image]

```
Cannot access 'java.lang.Object' which is a supertype of 'org.gradle.plugin.use.PluginDependenciesSpec'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Cannot access 'java.lang.Comparable' which is a supertype of 'org.gradle.api.Project'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Cannot access 'java.lang.Object' which is a supertype of 'org.gradle.api.Project'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

Answer (score 1):

It is Android Studio bug and it seems [resolved in Android Studio Giraffe Canary 1 (2022.3.1.1)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236692992). As a workaround you can delete `jdk.table` file from AS config folder. Location of this folder can be found [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-3769) in comments section. For Windows, location is `~/Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/Google/<Your Android Studio folder>/options`.